# round() Error in function_list[[i]](value) : object not found in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rounding

After a decent break from working with R, I am encountering an issue. Currently, I am working with a data frame with two columns. My goal is to round the first column `fheight` to then filter and selectively add both `fheight` and `sheight` to a new data frame if it is equal to 71. When I add the round() function I receive the error `Error in function_list[[i]](value) : object 'fheight' not found`.

```
father.son.adjusted <- father.son %>% 
  group_by(fheight) %>%
  round(fheight) %>% 
  filter(fheight == 71) %>% 
  select(fheight, sheight)
```

My data is numeric as follows

```
    
    fheight     sheight
1   65.04851    59.77827
2   63.25094    63.21404
3   64.95532    63.34242
4   65.75250    62.79238
5   61.13723    64.28113
6   63.02254    64.24221
7   65.37053    64.08231
8   64.72398    63.99574
```

When I run this snippet without the round function everything works fine. I read other questions regarding issues with the round function but was unable to decipher my own error. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and check this:

```
library(dplyr)
father.son.adjusted <- father.son %>%
  mutate(fheight=round(fheight)) %>%
  group_by(fheight) %>%
  filter(fheight == 71) %>% 
  select(fheight, sheight)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. I probably should have figured out using `mutate` was the next step. I appreciate the time

Comment: @ChrisEwanik Great! If you feel comfortable with this solution, just accept it! :) Happy for helping you.